# I want to allow html in my own text but that text is being escaped

Tags: python, google-app-engine, html-escape-characters

My html template contains the following code.

```
<a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>{{url_linktextmore}}
```

My Python code contains the following snippet.

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
                        url_linktextmore = '  after you signin. <strong> You may have mispelled your group. </strong>'
                    template_values = {
                        'url': url,
                        'url_linktext': url_linktext,
                        'url_linktextmore': url_linktextmore,
                        }
                    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'place.html')
                    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

My problem is that the `strong` is being escaped (for example, < is converted to `&lt;`) by the automatic templating system and I don't know how to  keep the bold type. This seemed to work  in an early version of my app, but no more.

This may be related to "magic quotes", but I don't know how to turn the "feature" off.

Brian in Atlanta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Jinja2 templating, you can do the following:

```
{{ url_linktext|safe }}
```

See [this link](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#html-escaping) for Jinja2 HTML escaping.

Note that the 'safe' filter is only required if you have the 'autoescape' extension added to your jinja2 Environment. eg:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])
```

Removing this extension may suit you better.

Comment: Maybe it is best if OP keeps autoescapeing since there may be cases where he would not want users to post unsafe text.

Comment: Using `save` as you suggested, not only helped with the example I gave but much more importantly fixed a problem I just noticed with my captcha.